# Proving $(\cos x +i\sin x)^n= \cos nx+i\sin nx$ by mathematical induction

Tags: trigonometry, induction

Prove $(\cos x +i\sin x)^n= \cos nx+i\sin nx$ by mathematical induction.

Hence, express $1-i$ in the form of $r(\cos x+i\sin x )$.

Comment: You should ask questions here. This is not a question. It looks like a copied and pasted homework problem with no indication that you understand what is said --- i.e. that any question is present in your mind.

Comment: An inductive proof is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2098995/409). Perhaps this question should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Blue You are right but that totally destroys the meaning of MSE for this particular question.

Comment: @MrYouMath: Far be it from me to destroy the meaning of MSE!

Comment: @Blue It was a dilemma, in this case, duplicates also destroy the meaning of MSE :D.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The case $n=1$ is trivial. Then show that

$$(\cos x+i\sin x)^2 = \cos 2x +i \sin 2x$$

by using

$$ \cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b \qquad (1)$$
$$\sin(a+b)= \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a. \qquad (2)$$

Then assume 
$$(\cos x + i \sin x )^n = \cos nx + i \sin nx$$ 
for $n\leq N$ then use the induction step $n \to n+1$

$$(\cos x + i \sin x )^{n+1} = (\cos x + i \sin x )^n(\cos x +i\sin x)=(\cos nx + i \sin nx)(\cos x +i\sin x)$$

and use $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Add what you have tried and tell us where and why you are stuck.

Comment: Well, maybe expand it. Then we have $ \cos nx \cos x+i \sin x \cos x+ i \sin nx \cos x +i^2 \sin nx \sin x$. After that, by (1) and (2) we can obtain  $ \sin(nx+x)+\cos nx \cos x+ i^2 \sin x \sin nx$

Comment: Ok, use $i^2=-1$ and collect real and imaginary parts then apply (1) for the real part and (2) for the imaginary part separately.

Comment: @AstridL thats correct, so now you have $\cos(nx)\cos(x)-\sin(nx)\sin(x)+i[\sin(nx)\cos(x)+\cos(nx)\sin(x)]$, on which you can apply the addition identities

Comment: A final question. Actually I don't really get how Mathematical Induction works. How can you just assume the statement is correct and do the following solution?

Comment: You only assume the formula to be correct for $n\leq N$. After doing the induction step, in which you only use the statement for $n\leq N$, you show that we can always increase the upper bound by one and so forth.

Comment: @AstridL; You prove something is true for $n=1$ by plugging in $n=1$ and showing it works (or another base case where applicable but usually when $n=1$). Then you assume it true for some $k$, and show that IF it is true for $n=k$, that it is also true for $n=k+1$. Thus, as you have already shown it is true for $n=1$, it must also be true for $n=2, n=3, n=4$ etc...

Comment: @AstridL: Induction is like spreading a rumor on a schoolbus. After all, it's human nature that some kid on any row of the bus who hears a rumor will "pass it on" to a kid in the following row. Consequently, telling a rumor to a kid in the front row guarantees that every row will hear it! With induction, you prove that the truth of a formula gets "passed on" from a step $k$ to a step $k+1$. Then, showing that the formula holds for *a particular* $k$ guarantees that it holds for every $k$ thereafter! (Usually, the "a particular $k$" part is done first, with a very small $k$, because it's easy.)

Comment: @Blue: Good explanation. Thanks a lot.